# Cant seem to get my php contact form working

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have a form called contact-us-html

```
<section id="contact-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row contact-wrap"> 
            <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
            <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email *</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>                       
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subject *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Message *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Please add who referred you if applicable"></textarea>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
</section><!--/#contact-page-->
```

then i have the sendmail.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
);

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'myemail@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

The email is being sent just fine however the body isnt being filled with the post data ?
[image: email snapshot]

this is driving me insane could someone please take a look, i know im just missing something small! Thanks!

Comment: Are you obtaining your $_POST variables properly? Try this on the top of your php file: `print_r($_POST); die;` to see what you're getting. If you have problem with it, try adding this property to your `<form>` tag: `enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: After `<?php` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and remove `@`from `mail()`, and check once.

Comment: @charles could you put ur ajax function pls.

Comment: @EduardoEscobar it just shows "undefined" and doesnt send the email anymore

Comment: Are you sure its not something simple like White Text on a White Background?

Comment: @RiggsFolly nope already tried highlighting

Comment: Are you using ajax anywhere? because your code works for me

Comment: @Anant im not using any ajax, you can check the website greenzip.com

Comment: @Anant i did a search for ajax and there appears to be some within my Jquery.js fle

Comment: your current code working fine for me.